# Apache Cordova: Keyboard adjust webview

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, cordova, webview

I've been building an app using apache cordova and Visual Studio as my IDE that is supposed to run on Android and iOS and I would like to know how to make it so that the keyboard doesn't affect the webview.

The input boxes and buttons remain the same but the background image keeps adjusting when the keyboard pops up. Here's my code:

```
body{ 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#000000;
    background: url(../images/landscape.jpg);
    background-size: 360px 568px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 360px 568px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}


var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

document.getElementById("body-tag").style.backgroundSize = w + 'px' + " " + h + 'px';
document.getElementById("body-tag").style.boxShadow = w + 'px' + " " + h + 'px' + " " + "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset";


function myFunction() {
    var wo = window.outerWidth;
    var ho = screen.height;

    document.getElementById("body-tag").style.backgroundSize = wo + 'px' + " " + ho + 'px';
    document.getElementById("body-tag").style.boxShadow = wo + 'px' + " " + ho + 'px' + " " + "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset";
}
```

I also even tried adding this to the config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
</platform>
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: so i changed the extra code in my config.xml to: <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" /> and i checked my AndroidManifest.xml after building the apk and it said android:windowSoftInputMode="10". why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use window resize event like below,

window.addEventListener('resize', me.onWindowResize, me);

```
  onWindowResize: function(e)
    {
        var me = this;
        window.scrollTo(0, 100);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', me.onWindowResize);
    },
```